# Get full HTTP request description via TShark

Tags: http, sniffer, tshark

I need to get full description of the HTTP requests with TShark sniffer. I mean something like Wireshark's GUI where you can get:

- raw request data (zipped/unzipped);
- pretty printed extracted HTTP fields: (Host, Accepted-Encoding, Cookies, etc).

For now I'm able to dissect HTTP with:

```
 tshark -i eth0 -f 'dst host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' -d tcp.port=80,http
```

it prints something like this:

```
139389.228821 x.x.x.x -> y.y.y.y HTTP GET /test.html HTTP/1.1
```

or I can print cookie (or all cookies?) for example with:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f 'dst host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' -T fields -e http.cookie
```

But I want complete HTTP request description with raw data. Is it possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Note: See comments for accepted answer.**

Curl might be able to do this for you.  when you post your data via curl, use the `-v` and `-i` options. You can also use `-b` and `-c` to read/write cookie info to a file so you can look at it.

This may not be exactly what you want as it sounds like you already have a program thats doing the posting but if you can re-create the post and send with curl, you'll see all of the raw data (when using the right options).

Curl docs are [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: I do need sniffer to debug behavior ot the specific program.

Comment: I guess if you are already working with tshark, could you grab all tcp traffic to a specific port, save that output somewhere. You will be able to reconstruct the converstations and get the raw data that way - as long as its HTTP not HTTPS!

Comment: ah, try the -V flag to tshark.  Just seen it on this http://linux.die.net/man/1/tshark

Comment: Ok. I'll give '-V' a try. Thanks.

Comment: -V (and -w for raw data) return everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only to monitor traffic from your own computer, try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Or use Firefox's Firebug, and/or Live HTTP Headers, and/or the Web Developer Toolbar

Comment: It's a Linux server with console. Don't think I can use Fiddler. Anyway, if I had GUI I would use Wireshark instead of TShark.